# How to get the email-address of the sender of an email using Gmail Python API

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

Using the Google API python client, I want to find the email address/ name of the sender of an email.
So far, I have extracted details about the message but I am having trouble finding a way to extract the finder's information.

Here is the code snippet:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

    Creates a Gmail API service object and outputs a list of label names
    of the user's Gmail account.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
    messages = results['messages']

    mail = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messages[0]['id'], format='minimal').execute()
    # I have other formats(RAW, METADATA and FULL) but I cannot parse them.
    print(mail)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am looking for some method(either built-in or third-party library) to parse the email object returned by the API to return a more readable information. Some ad-hoc method will also work for the time-being.

Answer (score 0):

I got an ad-hoc way to extract the basic information about an email.

Here is the snippet:

```
metadata = mail['payload']['headers'] 
# This list contains information about To, From and Subject among other gibberish.

for d in metadata:

    # for sender's information
    if d['name'] == 'From':
        print(d['value'])

    # for subject of the mail
    if d['name'] == 'Subject':
        print(d['value'])
```